# MVC Web API route not working with parameters. c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

my web api works fine when i request a route without parameters, but it doesnt find the controller when i add parameter:

This is my WebApiConfig.cs:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "v1/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { area = "v1", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This is my controller in the Area "v1":

```
[RoutePrefix("v1/Dummy")]
public class DummyController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    //[Route("")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

Here's what's right:
[image: CORRECT]
Here's What's Wrong:
[image: WRONG]

Can anyone please help with this ?

EDIT:

I have tho following code in Application_Start():

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

EDIT 2:

```
private void RegisterRoutes()
    {

        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("SumiService/Customer", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(SumiyCustomerService)));
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("SumiService", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(SumiService)));

        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("goops", new WindsorServiceHostFactory<RestServiceModel>(), typeof(IGoOpsService)));

        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("TempService", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(TempService)));
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Go", new WindsorServiceHostFactory<RestServiceModel>(), typeof(GoBusinessContracts.IGoService)));
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the code for route area register ?

Comment: @duongthaiha i added the code.

Comment: Your error message is coming from MVC, rather than Web API. What does your MVC route config look like?

Comment: @Kirk there is no further routing configuration. If you're referencing RouteConfig.cs, it's not registered in application start, and the file does not exist in App_Start

Comment: That's how I understood it. I've tried to reproduce this with all the information provided but it works as expected in my environment.

Comment: @Sam-Elie - Please edit the code you posted to *include the order in which the methods are called* and also post the code for `ServiceRoute`. Order is significant for routing, including the order the methods are called during startup (for example, whether MVC or WebApi routes are registered first).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **[FromRoute]** or **[FromUri]** attribute to your ID parameter:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public string Get([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
```

Comment: both attributes don't change behavior? Did you try [FromUri]?

Comment: No they do not. And yes i've tried both. And given that the request is not even reaching the route .. i hardly think these attributes would change anything regarding this matter.

Comment: OK, have you scaffolded new area v1? Do you have some v1AreaRegistration.cs in your silution? By default scaffolded area adds such registration of area-specific routes.Remove this file / routes registration